Methods For Reducing Output Voltage Of Pressure Sensor Into ADC
I am developing a data acquisition system that takes pressure readings from a pressure sensor. The pressure sensor is a bridge sensor which feeds into a differential ADC. The ADC has an input range of 0-5v (2.5v center). The pressure sensor has no specific voltage it needs to operate at, but all of its parameters are given at a 10v excitation voltage.
If I wanted to operate the sensor at 10v, wouldn't the output be outside of the voltage range of the ADC (5v quiescent point)? If so, how would I step down the output? I heard that a possible method would be to use an op amp buffer to isolate the pressure sensor and then a voltage divider to lower the output. Is this a good standard method, or are there alternative better ones?
Also, the ADC has "Offset Compensation" which can compensate for a sensor offset of up to 100% of the full-range output of a sensor. Does this have any relevancy to my issue?

Typically, sensors of this type (wheatstone bridge) are specced at 10 V but work just fine with 5 V excitation.  This is the approach I recommend for simplicity.
Offset compensation in your ADC is not for this purpose and won't help you here.  It can help you get your center point right, if that is important to you.
Another option is to run the signal through an instrumentation amplifier first, then to your ADC.  This is the approach I recommend for a more professional end product.

To make sure I understand properly, the IA would take the differential signal coming from the sensor (5v +- value with respect to GND in the 10v case) and output just the +- part at 0v with respect to GND which can then be fed into the ADC? In that case, there is no added benefit of a differential ADC over single ended right?

Exactly my thinking, yes.  You have an opportunity for scaling at the inst-amp level to get the best signal for your setup.
